# Can't adjust row with tkinter treeview

Tags: python, tkinter, row

I was making a treeview for my programm (tkinter). But I can't adjust the row.
Here is my code:

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
st=ttk.Style()
st.configure('MyStyle.Treeview', rowheight=100)
trv=ttk.Treeview(frame1,style='MyStyle.Treeview',column=(1,2,3,4), show="headings", height=6)
trv.pack(side=LEFT, expand=YES, fill=BOTH)
```

Thank u

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.
I used in my script a theme for my treeview (ttk.Style.theme_use()) which hid my code
After removing it it works
In fact I changed the order